# Error installing R package atSNP

Tags: r, installation, package

I am  trying to install an R package atSNP from https://github.com/chandlerzuo/atSNP. According to the documentation, this is how it is installed:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("chandlerzuo/atSNP")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Downloading github repo chandlerzuo/atSNP@master
Installing atSNP
Skipping 2 packages not available: GenomicRanges, motifStack
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/vt/nnrr0hts2h1bk6stsg4mt2xw0000gn/T/Rtmpzjo43z/devtoolsd9a33b03bdb4/chandlerzuo-atSNP-8cbe50e'  \
  --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘atSNP’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs
** R
** data
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
No methods found in "IRanges" for requests: sapply
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
No methods found in "IRanges" for requests: sapply
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

This is the session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] motifStack_1.12.0    Biostrings_2.36.1    XVector_0.8.0        ade4_1.7-2           MotIV_1.24.0         grImport_0.9-0      
 [7] XML_3.98-1.2         GenomicRanges_1.20.4 GenomeInfoDb_1.4.0   IRanges_2.2.2        S4Vectors_0.6.0      BiocGenerics_0.14.0 
[13] devtools_1.8.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5            GenomicAlignments_1.4.1 zlibbioc_1.14.0         BiocParallel_1.2.2      BSgenome_1.36.0        
 [6] lattice_0.20-31         stringr_1.0.0           httr_0.6.1              tools_3.2.0             seqLogo_1.34.0         
[11] lambda.r_1.1.7          futile.logger_1.4.1     git2r_0.10.1            rversions_1.0.0         digest_0.6.8           
[16] rtracklayer_1.28.4      futile.options_1.0.0    bitops_1.0-6            RCurl_1.95-4.6          memoise_0.2.1          
[21] rGADEM_2.16.0           stringi_0.4-1           Rsamtools_1.20.4
```

As you can see, I have installed & attached both packages GenomicRanges & motifStack and still the installation message says they are not available. I have tried uninstalling & reinstalling both the packages but I still get the same error. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I followed the suggestion below and still getting the following errors:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘atSNP’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
No methods found in "IRanges" for requests: sapply
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
No methods found in "IRanges" for requests: sapply
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP/libs/atSNP.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/atSNP’
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source package from the github website and install it. This gives no error on my Mac. In the terminal, type

`git clone git://github.com/chandlerzuo/atSNP.git`

`R CMD INSTALL atSNP`

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but it is still giving me the same error (see update above in my question). I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.

Comment: You can see that now there is no error regarding to the problem of loading motifStack and GenomicRanges, which is good. The remaining issue may relate to the configuration of R in MACs (see [1](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/373) ). I also encountered that problem for a while, but then I bumped into [2](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Tcl_002fTk-issues) and [3](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html) and followed their instructions, and the problem solved. Not an expert on operation system, but I hope these links can help.

Comment: I am really not sure what the problem could be. I following links 1 and 3 (installed Rcpp & Rcmdr) but nothing changes. I am honestly not sure what exactly to do with link 2.